# Trying to validate a RegExp in Flutter

Tags: regex, flutter, dart

I have a few reg expressions that work on dart but this one for some reason always returns false. I'm trying to validate an ID, code below

```
 if (RegExp(r'/^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{1}$/').hasMatch('123-1234-1234567-1')) {
              debugPrint('ID valid');
            } else {
              debugPrint('Invalid');
            }
```

Comment: 'new' is not necessary in Dart2.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Drop the slashes, regex delimiters are not needed:

```
print(RegExp(r'^[0-9]{3}-[0-9]{4}-[0-9]{7}-[0-9]{1}$').hasMatch('123-1234-1234567-1'));
```

prints `true`.